# Locked questions (including merge stubs) are still showing up in the "unanswered" list

Tags: bug, status-deferred, unanswered-questions, locked-posts, merged-questions

If you search for a given tag; say "JavaScript" in this case and look for "unanswered" to attempt to answer them you cannot if they are "merged" for example this question
[JavaScript: Why the anonymous function wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1643321/125981)

If you search "[JavaScript] anonymous function wrapper" it shows up as 0 answers:
[image: Question site visual]

Yet you CANNOT answer it.  **Instead of "0 answers" can this be altered to show "merged" or some such** and not show up for example if I search this it shows up:

```
[javascript] answers:0  "anonymous function wrapper"
```

Comment: Just add `locked:0`

Comment: I thought this bug was fixed [years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66068)...

Comment: Hello, I updated the status to [status-deferred] for now. There is going to be some additional work that needs to happen on the search page in terms of updating the UI to use our Stacks design system but we have tickets created and will provide updates once work on that has started. Thank you for your contributions!